# Chrome-extension: Programmatic way to open popup.html from background.html?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I'd like to open my popup.html from my background.html page. I'd also like to pass data using the same method also. Is this possible? Has anyone hacked a way in to doing this?

Comment: Do you want to open popup.html as a a new windows?
You can use tricks with url, like passing data after hash sign, which JS can read on other page.

Also I see no reason why google-chrome-extension is a tag for this question..

Answer (score 6):

You cannot do that. The popup should be user activated if you want it to be shown.

If you would like to use a method from the background page in the popup, you can access the background page by doing the following in your popup:

```
var bkg = chrome.extension.getBackgroundPage();
bkg.callFunction();
```

Comment: The problem is, I have context menu items which must access functions in the popup.html. The functions in the popup.html open dialog windows located within popup.html. IS there no way to do this in Chrome?

Comment: That is a design flaw then :) A popup page is alive when you click that button and disposes when it closes. Refactor out your logic outside the popup into a separate file that your background page (that hosts your context menu) and popup share. Or, place the functionality into the Background Page, and your popup can share that as I explained in my answer.

Comment: @Mohamed Mansour : You say that the popup should be user activated. Can a user open the popup through a context menu item?

Comment: @Shawn no, a popup cannot open by any action but clicking on it manually. If you want your context menu to open as a popup, you have to open that popup as a new tab with: `chrome.tabs.create({url: chrome.extension.getURL('popup.html')})` Which will run the exact same way as the popup but not within a popup.